# How to create a simple encryption algorithm in java?

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, encryption-symmetric

Guys can anyone guide me on how to create an algorithm for encryption/decryption in Java?  I need to make a client - server chat on which text needs to be encrypted by generating a key. On the receiver side the receiver receives text message with decrypt key to open the complete message.I have no idea. Will be grateful if anyone can provide me a sample or tutorial on this.

Comment: Please don't write your own encryption algorithm. Use one that is tried and tested.

Comment: Dan is completely correct here

Comment: Do you need to save the text? Otherwise communication with https should be sufficient I think.

Comment: Would you trust the security of your own sensitive information to software written by somebody who admittedly has "no idea"?

Comment: Use a well known/tested [library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) for such a delicate task

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you not create your own algorithm, but rather choose from a list of well known algorithms available in JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) or in Bouncy Castle, depending on if you accept third party software. Depending on what you're looking to do, you should choose your algorithm accordingly. Different types of sensitive data require different minimum levels of encryption.